# Neccesary/Sufficient Criteria for establishing discrete independence

Tags: probability

Question: Is  Joint density function of X and Y,  $\frac{16-4x-4y+xy}{36}$ for x=1,2,3 y=1,2,3 independent?

The solution to the question says yes, citing the observation that the above can be successfully decomposed into a product of x and y, namely $\frac{4-x}{4}\cdot\frac{4-y}{4}$. I see that this is necessary, but in terms of sufficiency, is it also necessary to make a table, plugging in all  value of x and y, and then comparing it to the product of the marginals, or is this step redundant?

Answer (score 1):

I read your question as: if the joint density*  can be factored as $p(x, y) = p_1(x) p_2(y)$, are we guaranteed that the probability of $(x,y)$ is equal to the product of the probabilities given by the marginals?

The answer is yes, because $p_1(x)$ and $p_2(y)$ *are* the marginals:
$$\int p(x,y) dy = \int p_1(x)p_2(y) dy = p_1(x) \left(\int p_2(y) dy\right) = p_1(x) \times 1.$$
Therefore, you are guaranteed that if $p(x,y)$ can be written as $p_1(x)p_2(y)$, that in the table of probabilities, each entry will be the product of its marginals, since it is equal to the product of $p_1(x)$ and $p_2(y)$.

*(actually, joint probability *mass* function, since $x,y$ are discrete)